# Error in bugzilla installation

Tags: mysql, bugzilla

I have installed bugzilla, now when I run checksetup.pl produce following error.

```
There was an error connecting to mysql:
       install_driver(mysql) failed. Attempt to reload DBD/mysql.pm aborted.
compilation failed in require at (eval 159) line 3.

       at Bugzilla/DB.pm line 1265.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not install DBD::mysql, which is the database driver for MySQL and the Perl DBI, which is what Bugzilla is using. Please check https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/DBD-mysql/lib/DBD/mysql/INSTALL.pod to see installation instructions for your platform.